# PATH broken when trying to add directory permanently for all users

Tags: rhel, sudo, environment-variables, path

> **What specific changes need to be made to the following in order to safely add the `/home/myapp-host/bin` directory location to the $PATH permanently for all users on Amazon Linux 2, which is based on RHEL?**

**FAILING SYNTAX:**

We ran the following two commands from the shell as `root`:

```
[root@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]# cat << 'EOF' >> /etc/profile.d/myapp.sh
> PATH=$PATH:/home/myapp-host/bin
> EOF

[root@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]# cat << 'EOF' >> /etc/environment
> PATH=$PATH:/home/myapp-host/bin
> EOF
```

**INITIAL VALIDATION AS 'root'**

Next, still in the same session as `root`, we validated the contents of the files created by the above commands, and we validated that contents of the `/home/myapp-host/bin` directory such as `bundle` were now visible to root though they have not been visible before the above `cat` commands, as follows:

```
[root@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]# cat /etc/profile.d/myapp.sh
PATH=$PATH:/home/myapp-host/bin
[root@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]# bundle -v
-bash: bundle: command not found
[root@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]# source /etc/profile
[root@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]# bundle -v
Bundler version 2.1.4
[root@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]# cat /etc/environment
PATH=$PATH:/home/myapp-host/bin
[root@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/myapp-host/bin:/root/bin
```

**BROKEN DURING NEXT NEW PUTTY SESSION:**

Third, we created an entirely new Putty session to ssh in again separately as a `sudo` user named `outside-user`, which is the primary login account for the instance, and is different from the `myapp-host` account.  You can see that access to commands such as `sudo` and `bundle` is broken as a result of the above commands, as follows:

```
[outside-user@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]$ sudo bundle -v
-bash: sudo: command not found
[outside-user@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]$ sudo su - myapp-host
-bash: sudo: command not found
[outside-user@ip-12-3-4-567 ~]$ echo $PATH
$PATH:/home/myapp-host/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/myapp-host/bin:/home/outside-user/.local/bin:/home/outside-user/bin
```

`outside-user` cannot elevate to `root` to determine if the `root` functionality has changed with the start of a new session, because `sudo` is among the broken items.

> **What specifically do we need to fix in the above so that access to commands like `sudo` is not broken, and so that `bundle` can become visible for `root` and for `sudoers` who type `sudo bundle`?**

Comment: I think you botched your default PATH in `/etc/environment` since `$PATH` is not expanded there. What happens if you append `:/home/myapp-host/bin` to the existing PATH definition or leave the file as it originally was?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does environment variable persistence break the PATH var?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279107/why-does-environment-variable-persistence-break-the-path-var)